# Sample size needed for a random effects model

Tags: statistical-significance, mixed-model, sample-size, random-effects-model, statistical-power

I am trying to understand what I need to calculate in order to determine the sample size needed for a linear mixed effects model. For each subject I will have 10 time points, at which I measure an outcome and two time-varying covariates, $X_1$ and $X_2$. I additionally will include a random intercept and slope, so the model looks like:

$$Y_{ij} = \beta_1 + \beta_2t_{ij} + \beta_3X_1 + \beta_4X_2 + b_{1i} + b_{2i}t_{ij}$$

- Time points $t_{ij}$ for subject $i$ with $j = 1,..., 10$
- $X_1$ is a continuous covariate
- $X_2$ is a binary covariate
- $b_{1i}$ and $b_{2i}$ represent the random intercept and slopes
- I want a power of 0.8, significance level of 0.05

**My goal is to be able to determine $\beta_4$ as significant above an estimated effect size of $\delta$.** I am a bit confused as to where to begin (or what assumptions need to be made) to calculate this. The main parameter of interest here is $\beta_4$ as I want to determine whether $X_2$ has a significant effect on the outcome, and determine the sample size needed in order to be able to pick up this significant effect.

---

Clearly there are certain values I'd have to estimate (e.g. variances of random effects), but my goal is to understand:

- Which formula(s) I can use for this type of sample size calculation and why
- Which values/parameters in this formula I'd need to estimate

And then I can take it from there.

Comment: I think there are only closed form equations for power for very simple tests (e.g. t-test). In all other situations you can simulate data, fit your model and see if you reject your null. Do this many times and the proportions of rejections is your power.

Comment: @bdeonovic could you describe how you would run a simulation for this mixed model setup?

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the R package `simr` (assuming of course you are comfortable working in R). Here is the associated [paper](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/2041-210X.12504) and a nice [slide-show-tutorial](https://med.und.edu/daccota/_files/pdfs/berdc_resource_pdfs/sample_size_r_module_glmm2.pdf)